# Keep a category in a filter selected, but hide it from the filter box

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a filter box with 4 categories in it, I want a  specific category to be always selected and the user to not be able to turn it off, so the user can only choose between the three other categories.

[image: current filter]

This is how the filter box currently looks, but I want it to look like this.

[image: what I want]

I tried to use the Page filter settings, however it unchecks the first emtpy category, which i want it to be always selected.

can you help me here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an easy way to achieve this. It can be done by using a Measure(s) which will need to be added to each and every visual on the page that you want to be sliced.

**Slicer**
Your slicer will need to be from a separate table to the ones used in a visual. If you don't have a separate table, then you can create one with:

```
Slicer Type = DISTINCT( 'YourTable'[Type] )
```

You don't need to have relationships created for this new table (but you can if you want).
In the Filter pane, hide the empty category.

**Measure**
Create a Measure similar to:

```
Type count = 
  CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('YourTable'),
    REMOVEFILTERS('Slicer Type'[Type]),
    KEEPFILTERS(
      'YourTable'[Type] IN DISTINCT('Slicer Type'[Type]) || 
      'YourTable'[Type] = ""
    )
  )
```

Add this measure to your visuals, or modify existing measures used in your visuals with the same concept as above.